# How to test whether an element has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that refreshes its data as follows

```
refresh: function($contentholder) {

    $contentholder.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass("Codes")) {
          //then it does some stuff in here
        }
      }
    }
```

the `$contentholder` comes in with data as follows

```
<div class="Codes" cod="t592">
  <h3></h3>
  <div class="Items">
    <div class="ItemCodes" id="592" time="2016/04/30 12:15" places="1"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The only way my if-statement gets detected, is if I check it as follows `$this.hasClass("Codes")`, but I only want the if-statement to get executed if the `hasClass("codes")` contains the class `ItemCodes`

This is what I tried but doesn't work

```
if ($this.hasClass("Codes").length > 0) //comes back undefined even though there is data
```

```
if ($this.hasClass("ItemCodes"))` //doesnt get detected
```

Basically, I want to do something like this

```
if ($this.hasClass("Codes").find("ItemCodes"))
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` to determine if there was any child `.ItemCodes` elements. You will need two separate conditions as these statements cannot be combined.

```js
refresh: function ($contentholder) {
  $contentholder.each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("Codes") && $this.find('.ItemCodes').length) {
      // do some stuff in here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but now if theres no "itemcodes" present its still going into that if statement,so its not actually checking if its in there or not

Comment: I'm unable to replicate that behaviour, the code above works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/n5Lreuk2/

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.is()` method combined with `:has()` pseudo selector as follows:

```
if ( $this.is('.Codes:has(".ItemCodes")') ) {
    //
}
```

```js
let $that = $('div.Codes');
console.log( $that.is('.Codes:has(".ItemCodes")') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Codes test me" cod="t592">
  <h3></h3>
  <div class="Items">
    <div class="ItemCodes" id="592" time="2016/04/30 12:15" places="1"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```